Second conditional VS should, happen to, should happen to
I've read in "Advansed grammar in use" (Raymond Murphy) that we use second conditional with present or future tenses when we talk about hypothetical situations. This conditional is unreal, so the probability of the fact that the case will happen isn't high.
And one more rule about phrases "should, happen to, should happen to". We may use them in real conditional, when something is unlikely to happen.
So I just don't understand the difference in meaning here:

If it happens to rain, I'll stay at home
If It rained, I’d stay at home

In first sentense is real conditional, but the situation is unlikely to happen, in the second one is unreal conditional about present/future and the situation is unlikely to happen again.
Is there any difference? And if there is, why do we use phrases with meaning "unlikely to happen" in real conditional, when usually is quite likely to happen?

The second is mixing up tenses improperly and doesn't make sense. "If it had rained, I would have stayed at home" is more correct.

I don't think there's a particular difference in meaning here. You can use adverbs and other constructions to modify the probability in conditional statements, just as you can in any other sentence. But why use extra words when you don't have to? Maybe in some situations it's clearer, or you'd do it for variety. Language offers limitless flexibility.

@Barmar thanks for your comment, but could you tell me please why do you think so? "If it had rained, I would have stayed at home" - is about past tense. That's why I'm comparing "If it happens to rain, I'll stay at home" and "If It rained, I’d stay at home", because both these sentences in present

I agree with you and disagree with @Barmar. As I see it, (1) is talking about the likelihood of it raining on a particular occasion in the future. (How likely it is depends on what part of the world you live in; to me in the UK it's a possibility that always has to be considered!)  (2) is more hypothetical - maybe the occasion is not a planned event but an imaginary one. "If I had been invited to a garden party and it rained that day, I would stay at home."

@KateBunting Maybe a difference of pond side (I'm American), but I'd say "If I'm invited to a garden party and it rains that day, I would stay home."
